# Solving $a \sin(bx + c) + d\sin(ex + f) = g$, where $a-g$ are constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Could anyone tell me how I can solve an equation of this form: $a\sin(bx + c) + d\sin(ex + f) = g$ Where the variables $a$ to $g$ are constants.

And does anyone know a place (i.e. a website) where I could learn things like this?

Comment: I suspect that, for the most general case, there is no analytical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The method below works only if b=e and c=f** See [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Simplifying_a_sin%28x%29_%2B_b_cos%28x%29) for a proof.

Use $\sin(\theta)=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$, then you obtain $a\sin(bx + c) + d\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-ex - f) = g$. Now use $A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(x+y)$ to obtain $$\sin(bx + c+y)=\frac{g}{\sqrt{a^2+d^2}},$$ where $y$ is such that $\cos y=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+d^2}}$. The rest should be standard.

Comment: Wrong! In $A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$, we have $x=x$, obviously and you are applying the formula with $x\ne x$, so to speak.

Comment: @  Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla: thanks, corrected the typo.

Comment: But the formula is with $x$ and $x$: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Simplifying_a_sin%28x%29_%2B_b_cos%28x%29. The $y$ appears only in the RHS.

Comment: Ups, you are right! only if $b=e$ and $c=f$, then the method would work ... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this you need to look at your trig rules to simplify the expressions like sin(ax + b). Have a look here : http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html

Comment: This is not even hint

Comment: Thank you :) I'll try to use some of these and see if I can work it out